# ASP Classic INSERT script does not create a new record

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am having this really bizarre issue where I have an asp page that tries to action multiple insert scripts one after the other. In this case it is 2 inserts. One of the inserts will run fine and work, the other however, seems to run (ie no errors are thrown to the screen) but no record is created. If I dump the SQL to screen and run in SQL Management Studio, it inserts fine.

Would really appreciate some help if someone has experienced this before.

Code block:

```
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
    Conn.Open strDBConn

    Set CreateGRNHeaderEntryCMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    CreateGRNHeaderEntrySQL = "INSERT INTO whGRN(grn_Ref, grn_Created, grn_CreatedBy, grn_Status)"_
                            & " VALUES('GRN0857-13', GetDate(), 'Scanner','NEW')"

    CreateGRNHeaderEntryCMD.CommandText = CreateGRNHeaderEntrySQL
    Set CreateGRNHeaderEntryCMD.ActiveConnection = Conn
    Set CreateGRNHeaderEntryRS = CreateGRNHeaderEntryCMD.Execute
```

Comment: Do you close your connection?  Do you execute the second INSERT on the same connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was causing the issue, there were a `Trigger` setup against the database that was performing a rollback.